# How to call button Clicked method from somewhere else

Tags: iphone, button

I am developing an application in which I want to select the button with some given tag. For example tag=12. So, what I want is  that when the button with tag 12 is selected the button clicked method also gets called.

One more thing I want to ask, if I write

```
button.selected=YES
```

will the button method automatically get called? If not then how to call the button method from somewhere else where I do not have sender (button properties) value?

The only thing I have is the button tag.

Please help and ask me for any clarification.

Comment: you want to select the button without user interaction? am i right?

Comment: yes..actually i am using a scroll view and a remote...So when i will press some number in remote ..that button should be selected in scroll view...Kindly get back to me for any clarification

Comment: You can take the UIButton object as UIButton * btn = (UIButton *)[self.scrollview viewWithTag:12]; Then call it's IBAction method on that object.

Comment: @Arya..thanks..it helped

Comment: ok..I was not knowing Sir...But i will do now..does it increase by clicking on the check mark on the right hand side of question

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary UIButton and give the tag of button you want to call.

For eg. call button action method with temporary button of tag 12

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button.tag = 12;
[self buttonTapped:button];
```

Hope it helps. Comment down for any query.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting button's property to **Selected** manually , then for it's click event you will have to call it manually , When you set button **Selected** like :

```
[self buttonCick];
```

Answer (score 1):

iUser is close.  You'll want to call the method you've linked to your button manually.

```
[self buttonClick:nil]
```

will work, if you're calling the buttonClick method from an object of the same class that contains the buttonClick method.  Otherwise, you'll need to keep a reference to the object (perhaps a controller) containing the buttonClick method and use that instead of self.

```
[self.controller buttonClick:nil];
```